# Open Link in Safari instead of native app with https URL

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, safari

I have a `NSString *htmlString` that displays a button in HTML to open Telegram.

I have tried `<a href='https://t.me/*********official' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Join on Telegram</a>` but this just opens directly in-app.

My second theory was to try `<a href='window.open('https://t.me/*********official')' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Join on Telegram</a>` with the same results. How do I open this link with Objective-C htmlString in safari instead of directly in the application?